# what does autoAck in akka camel consumer mean?

Tags: akka, consumer

autoAck in akka camel consumer returns boolean true or false.

if autoAck = true, how does the consumer do when the message enters the consumer's mailbox but before the consumer processes the message?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you looking for anything else than what is documented here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/java/camel.html#Delivery_acknowledgements

Comment: i am reading the "Delivery acknowledgements" section in Camel(scala) doc (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/camel.html). it mentioned autoAck and i do not fully understand the role of autoAck.

Answer (score 0):

When `autoAck=true` the sender will not wait for the message to be processed by the consumer actor. In other words, the following send will return immediately:

```
camel.template.asyncSendBody("direct:my-endpoint", "some message").get(timeoutDuration.toSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

When `autoAck=false` the above `get` will block until you send the `Ack` or `Failure` or timeout.

Comment: many thanks. I will look at Camel document to see if camel.template.asyncSendBody() returns, does it mean the message is received at the endpoint.