# does akka camel consumer dequeue message before processing the message or after processing message?

Tags: message, akka, consumer

```
class MyConsumer1 extends Consumer {
  def endpointUri = "some protocol string"

  def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage ⇒ // processing msg
  }
}
```

MyConsumer1 is a general form of camel consumer.

Questions: 
Is msg in receive() de-queued first before invokeing or after receive()? 
how does the endpoint protocol and autoAck influence the dequeue behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what dequeue you mean here. The message that you are processing inside the Consumer Actor is no longer in the Actors mailbox since it is being processed, but that doesn't mean that the Endpoint isn't waiting for the Actor to Ack the message that it is processing before it is removed from some Queue that the Endpoint is working with.

I think that the autoAck question was already answered in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679789/what-does-autoack-in-akka-camel-consumer-mean)